# How to write jest unit test to verify Nebula logger methods are called

Tags: lightning-web-components, lwc-jest

I am using Nebula logger in my lwc to log errors but lost on how to write jest unit test that verifies nebula logger methods are actually called.

Here is sample code:

**myLwc.js**

```
import { createLogger } from 'c/logger';

const logger = createLogger();

export function myMethod() {
    try {
        throw new Error('failed');
    } catch (error) {
        logger.error(`Error occured`);
        logger.saveLog();
    }
}
```

**myLwc.test.js:** (What should I add in place of comments in this file?)

```
import { myMethod } from '../myLwc';

describe('c-my-lwc', () => {    
    it('test myMethod', () => {
        myMethod();
        /* ======> What should I assert here to make sure nebula is called as expected? <======*/
    });
});
```

**jest.config.js:**

```
const { jestConfig } = require('@salesforce/sfdx-lwc-jest/config');

module.exports = {
    ...jestConfig,
    modulePathIgnorePatterns: ['<rootDir>/.localdevserver'],
    moduleNameMapper: {
        '^c/logger': '<rootDir>/force-app/test/jest-mocks/c/logger.js'
    }
};
```

**force-app/test/jest-mocks/c/logger.js**:

```
export const createLogger = () => {
    return {
        error: jest.fn(),
        saveLog: jest.fn()
    };
};
```

I think solution is something to do with `jest.mock` and `toHaveBeenCalled` but I am not able to come up with a proper solution.

Answer (score 2):

I was able to solve by applying this approach: [ES6 Class Mocks: Manual Mock](https://jestjs.io/docs/es6-class-mocks#manual-mock)

**force-app/test/jest-mocks/c/logger.js:**

```
export const mockErrorFunction = jest.fn();
export const mockSaveFunction = jest.fn();

export const createLogger = jest.fn().mockImplementation(() => {
    return { error: mockErrorFunction, saveLog: mockSaveFunction };
});
```

**myLwc.test.js:**

```
import { myMethod } from '../myLwc';
import { mockErrorFunction, mockSaveFunction } from 'c/logger';

describe('c-my-lwc', () => {
    it('test myMethod', () => {
        jest.mock('c/logger');
        myMethod();
        expect(mockErrorFunction).toHaveBeenCalledWith('Error occured');
        expect(mockSaveFunction).toHaveBeenCalled();
    });
});
```